# Export gridview to MS word preserving formatting

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to export a gridview to MS word and keep the formatting from the gridview.  The code below works to export the gridview but I cannot figure out how to keep the formatting.  (I cannot use any 3rd party software)

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.doc")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"

    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you are defining most of the Grid's colors, column alignments etc, via `classes` defined in a `CSS` file and when you export, these classes can no longer be referenced.

To fix it, you need to use inline styles so that the HTML rendered is self-contained and the colors and other formatting is preserved when the grid is written as a Word document.

Comment: @Mike yes, set the style in the grid to use inline styles such as `BackgroundColor="#FDFDFD"` instead of using css classes such as: `ItemCssClass="rowclass"`

Answer (score 0):

This sample from forums.asp.net claims to do the job:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileEName.doc");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
this.EnableViewState = false;
Response.Write(word.InnerHtml);
Response.End();
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1823755.aspx/1

Comment: using `InnerHtml` works if the styles are defined on the element directly instead of through CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

```
     >First bind your grid 
     >Response.ClearContent();
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; 
       filename={0}", "Customers.doc"));              

     Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
   ><%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Records.aspx.cs"  
       Inherits="Records"
     MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"  EnableEventValidation="false" %>
   >use this code if img click event not fired
     protected void mswrd_imgbtn_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
    ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
    ScriptManager sc = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    sc.RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
     }
```